# Get original $request in a listener which implements ShouldQueue in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, events, laravel-5

I need to get an original `Request` (specifically `Request::server()`) in my listeners for these Laravel internal events:

- `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login`
- `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed`

Understandably, I cannot use values Request returns in my listener, since it's constructed separately server-side on queue.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of the listener you can save the request to a member of the class, then you will be able to use it inside the handle function. For example:

```
class LogSuccessfulLogin implements ShouldQueue
    {
    protected $request;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Login  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        // here you can use $this->request->ip(); for example.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution will not work, sorry, I already mentioned that in my question.

Comment: I've tested and it works, if it doesn't work for you try not saving the complete request in the constructor but the fields you need (for example $this->request->ip());

Comment: Are you saying that you are getting client's IP and not server IP with $this->request->ip()? Double check that, mate :D

Comment: If you are running server on the same IP your client on, get $this->request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT') instead of IP. Otherwise it will work again for you :)